# Looking for a way to diff many server's filesystem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

There's a motivation in my office to make sure that all file systems on all servers in the production environment (It's a Windows environment) are identical until the last file and i'm looking for a program/tool which can help me achieve this goal.
What i actually look for is a tool that will allow me to diff server's file systems by connecting them remotely (as they are spreaded around the world).
Anyone knows a tool which allows it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the net for quite some time i came by a product which i actually used about a year ago for another reason.
There's a very cool application which is called ControlUp by a company named Smart-x, the program allows you (along with a whole lot of other features) to add any number of servers and then from a simple right click menu you can choose to diff as many servers as you like, on the right pane it will show you the file system tree and the delta's will be displayed in red color.
The application is also Citrix Ready.

Answer (score 0):

You could try cwRsync. See https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync

See also this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

rsync with the -n flag will compare files without transfering them.  You'd have to install one of the windows rsync variants on each server.

Or use a powershell or batch script to calculate the MD5sum of each file and write it to a file.  Then compare the files from each server.

Keep in mind the servers shouldn't be identical - things like log files and registries will be different.

Comment: The same can be done using robocopy with the /L switch. It's very similar to rsync and it's included with newer versions of Windows.